# Two dice throwing game issue

Tags: java, random

My program needs to throw 2 dices and when both are 6 it gets out of the loop and show me how many times it tries, but for some reason I get very wierd try numbers like, most of them are "it took 1-3 tries".. 
Help plz.

```
public class SheshBesh {
public static void main(String[] args){

    int r1 = 0;
    int r2 = 0;
    int tries = 0;

    while (r1 != 6 && r2 != 6) {
        r1 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        r2 = (int)(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        tries = tries + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Shesh-Besh apears... it took " + tries + " tries.");


}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried adding `System.out.println("tries:" + tries + " r1:" + r1 + " r2:" + r2)` to the while loop, so you can trace the execution of the program and what happened each time through the loop?

Comment: @DevinHoward You're right, i'll try that, thank you.

Comment: Works here `Shesh-Besh apears... it took 3 tries.`, so not sure what is different on your end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left a comment about debugging, which should help you in the future with these kinds of errors. You need to be able to trace the execution of the program so you can start to reason about why it's failing.

The reason is this line:

`while (r1 != 6 && r2 != 6)`

If r1 is 6 and r2 is 4, this will evaluate to false, and exit the loop.

You should change it to one of:

`while (r1 != 6 || r2 != 6)`

or even the more instructive:

`while (!(r1 == 6 && r2 == 6))`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `while (r1 != 6 || r2 != 6)`, which is, according to De Morgan's law, equivalent to `while ( ! (r1 == 6 && r2 == 6) )`.

Otherwise, as in your question, `while (r1 != 6 && r2 != 6)` stops when *either* r1 or r2 is equal to 6. This is equivalent to `while ( ! (r1 == 6 || r2 == 6) )`.

Comment: But the && sign means "and" so I don't understand

Comment: @LiziPizi Added explanation. Search for "De Morgan's law".